# Reading data from file object javascript gives undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, file, dom, readfile

I am trying to read the content of a file into an array to be processed. Here is my attempt try and get the data of the file into a variable:

```
var theFile = document.getElementById("getFile");
var fileVal = theFile.files[0];
var dataFromFile = fileVal.getAsDataURL();
alert(dataFromFile);
```

But where I try to pass dataAsUrl to the dataFromFile variable it gives me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

As a side note, this is part of a game project where we are only aloud to use pure JavaScript.

Comment: Can you post some more specifics to what your data looks like. It would be really helpful to see what fileVal actually is.

Comment: Do you mean the document I am loading? If so it contains only digits and newline characters. If you mean what is stored in the fileVal variable it says : [object file].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. 
Do not use it in old or new projects. 
Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

The getAsDataURL provides a data: URL that encodes the entire contents of the referenced file.

Note: This method is obsolete; you should use the FileReader method readAsDataURL() instead.

Here is the live example.. jsfiddle.net/fKQDL/

Comment: Thank you very much. I just have a small problem and that the files data is stored in the variable only after the I exit the main function. If I click on the button again then I see that the file is stored in the variable. Is there a way to say to continue with the code after the file has been read and the data stored? (I used the readAsText function instead)